# How to get the address of a label at compile time

Tags: assembly, nasm

Is there a way to get Nasm to tell you the address of a particular label? For instance

```
 ; blah blah blah...

 _routine:
     ; do some stuff

 ; blah blah blah
```

I want to know what the address of `_routine` is *at compile time*. In other words, *I, personally* want to know what the address is (as opposed to having the value accessible within the program).

Comment: You have no idea at what address will your code be loaded. So the best you can get is the label's RVA (relative virtual address) - that's the offset from the module's starting address. For those, generate the map file and see. To appear in the map file, the label must be globally visible (i. e. exported).

Comment: That's a good point for certain output formats, but I'm generating `bin` format, so it knows the modules starting address (via the `org` directive) and the map file generates correct absolute addresses (virtual or physical is irrelevant). Also, there doesn't seem to be any requirement that the labels be specially marked for export or global: all my labels (even nested ones) are appearing the in the map file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, you can put this bit of magic in *your source file* (crazy nasm...)

```
[map all myfile.map]
```

Comment: `[map ...]` works only in `-f bin` mode (normally a linker function). A list file may help... `-l myfile.lst`. The address at assemble-time is not that interesting a number, usually...

Comment: Thanks for the tip. `bin` is fine for me, but may not be for others. I'm developing a bootloader/kernel with `qemu` and haven't figured had any luck loading debug info into `gdb` yet. I need the address of the label so I can set a break point.

Comment: @brianmearns, so what have ypu added in your asm code ? because I had same question recently https://stackoverflow.com/q/55032858/8313610

Comment: Sorry @Elvin, this was years ago and I can barely even make sense of my question anymore, let alone remember how I solved it =/ Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You should just be able to use the label's name. Labels in NASM are automatically treated as addresses.

Therefore:

```
 mov   rax,label_name
```

Should get you the address.

Comment: Thanks, but I guess I wasn't clear enough. I meant that *I* need to know the address, not just my program. I'll edit my question to make this more clear.

Comment: Declare the label as public or global and it should appear in a map or linker file. Or you can use what I wrote above and then print to screen on boot.