# How to use debugging tools to your own kernel

Tags: c, assembly, operating-system

I've my own boot.asm which boots my PE kernel.cpp. So I need to see and be aware of every step done in kernel in debugging purposes. How can I connect gdb with qemu if I have to use windows.